# Dell SC1435 always requires F1 at boot

Tags: dell, bios

I have a Dell PowerEdge SC1435 that has come back after doing duty at a partner site.  I am trying to configure it for local use.  The only problem I have with it is that every time it boots it always requres a manual F1 press after the POST sequence.

The last thing it does is give me the opportunity to configure the BMC, and then it says:

```
Press F1 to continue or press F2 for Setup
```

It will wait there forever (well, at least an hour).  Pressing F1 starts the OS booting.

I can't see the setting in the BIOS which controls this and I can't find it in the documentation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a RAID option.  As a result, the SATA drives are connected to the RAID card and not the motherboard.

The first thing it complains about at boot time, immediately after the Dell splash screen but before the rest of the POST, is:

```
SATA Device 1: device not found
SATA Device 2: device not found
```

Going into the BIOS and changing the SATA devices from AUTO to OFF removed these two errors, and now the computer boots through properly.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when I see this behavior it's due to a dead bios battery.  So everytime the machine boots it wants you to go into the bios to setup things.

This is complaining about the BMC so have you tried to go into it and set it up properly or at least go in there and save the configuration it has currently.  If that doesn't work look to see if the BMC has it's own battery.  If so I would replace it try again.

Comment: The system clock kept good time while it was in transit (a week or more), and the documentation suggests that if the system battery is no good the computer will complain about it during the POST sequence, which it doesn't.  I will double-check, and look into the BMC config.

Comment: Yeah but it's complaining about the BMC not the Bios.  So see if it has its own battery.  In which case it may be dead.

Comment: Configured the BMC, no change.

Comment: Figured it out.  Your answer got me looking more closely at ALL the output the computer was telling me.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is a sounding board.

Answer (score 1):

I went through several forums trying to find an answer for this.  I tried several of the suggestions but what ended up working for me was disabling IDE.  I noticed that I was also getting a "CD-ROM failed to load" message and so figured I didn't need it anyway.  After this the F1, F2 prompt went away.  Hope this helps someone.